# Removing Home Directory of Deleted Users in FreeIPA

Tags: freeipa

Title says it. I tried looking up for documentation about how the home directory of a user can be removed after the end of its life cycle but there seems to be nothing. Is there any function in FreeIPA that can automate this process withou resorting to Ansible/Salt/the-like?

Comment: Since only the home directory *"attribute"*  is stored in FreeIPA, that is AFAIK also the only thing you can delete using FreeIPA and you need something else to delete actual directories. Especially when you use pam_mkhomedir and no central NFS/file with shared homeDirectories   **a** home directory can potentially exist on every system a user may have accessed.

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks. Guess I'll use some config management tool.